# Removing old caulk to clean mold, started pulling up unknown layer

Tags: tile, bathtub, grout, caulking

I'm removing some old caulk from my tub to deal with some mildew (photo below). While stripping the caulk, I've started pulling up an unknown piece behind the caulk (second photo). My initial thought was this was a piece of grout between the tile and the tub but there is a regular pattern on the back (third photo) so now I'm not sure. Should I avoid taking this extra piece out? In general, it's easier to get them both out together because the the caulk is so old

#### Old caulk with mildew:

[image]

#### Mystery piece

[image]

#### Regular pattern

[image]

Comment: Probably old grout and pattern from bottom of tiles.  Is it hard like grout?

Comment: yea it's pretty hard. interesting point about getting the pattern from bottom of the tile. Shouldn't the tile be flush with the tub normally? If it is grout, should I try to keep it in there? Or alternatively, could we pull the old grout out and replace it?

Comment: If it is pulling up, just removed it all and replace with new.  Will find the pattern on something there, tile, bathtub or tile spacer.  Make sure everything nice and clean before replacing/redoing.